# Laravel - login page redirecting back to homepage, but only on production

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I can access my login page using the URL on my homepage - `/login`, and login to the site as expected. However, in production, if I click the link to login, it "processes" and then redirects back to the homepage.

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ url('login') }}">Login</a>
</li>
```

I have the logs set to daily within my application, however, nothing is 'erroring'.

How can I debug this in production? I'm using Laravel Forge. Why would the standard `/auth/login` URL not work in production, but on local?

I've just pushed my latest build to prod, so they're both using the exact same code base. I have also cleared all configs/caches on `php artisan`.

If you require further code/information, please just let me know.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why dont you use `action()` instead of `url()` the problem is most likely in the way url is formed. When you inspect the link is the location correct?

Comment: What's the state of your **.env** file? What's the `APP_DOMAIN` global on production environment?

Comment: `APP_DOMAIN` isn't set in neither local or production

Comment: Is the link `url` good when you inspect the tag on **production**?

Comment: Probably caused by cookie not getting set properly. Inspecting the network while preserving the log (HTTP headers, redirection log) should provide you with more info to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your browser cache/cookies and try again.
2. Check for any server configurations differences between production and development.
3. Are you 100% sure that both environment has identical code?